# XMPP and Android interaction

Tags: android, jms, xmpp, activemq-classic, smack

I am currently finding about how to build a XMPP client application on android 2.1.I came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596855/interaction-between-java-and-android) which somewhat talks about the same problem.I am a newbie to android dev and thus found the solution given there to be difficult to digest.

The system currently has Active MQ as a JMS provider.My job is to fed the messages coming from JMS to the XMPP server and then develope XMPP client on android 2.1 which will listen and show notification to the events pushed by the server.

I have following concerns(which might sound foolish)
1.How do I push the events from JMS to the XMPP server which will in turn push them on android?

2.Which XMPP server implementation I should use?I have 3 options 
    * Openfire: Very mature (was a commercial product), but sounds like it's  heavyweight, written in Java
    * Prosody: Lightweight and easy to use, written in Lua. Doesn't have PubSub module yet
    * Tigase: Also lightweight, written in Java, supports PubSub
How do I test and setup these servers.Do I need PubSub funcationality for my app?

3.For XMPP client I came across Smack API given [here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/) which is updated like 2 years back.Can anyone please tell me how do I make use of it for Android 2.1.If possible can anyone please mail me latest working Smack jar files.

Thanks,
Ameya

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use eJabberd as your XMPP server ? It seems to me that is has the best support of pubsub and is a very efficient server. We use it since 2 years now without any issue. And on the client side, yes, asmack if definitively the open source choice, but has some drawbacks: it does not support pubsub, and has some very nasty bugs that you will encounter if you dive into some of its functionalities. We had to improve and extend it a lot to implement our full featured social network IM/microbloging/geolocalisation client for Android (called BuddyMob) and now we provide an extended version of Smack as a commercial product (see http://www.ubikod.com/products.htm). Some of our bug fixes has been integrated into the Smack trunk, but most of the extensions we did are not free.

Comment: asmack doesn't support pubsub ?? then whats this ? http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/pubsub.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at asmack for an android Smack client: http://code.google.com/p/asmack/

Answer (score 0):

You can push messages from JMS to XMPP using Apache Camel - http://camel.apache.org/xmpp.html